# Error: Cannot interpret this number as a value of type nat

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

My current goal is:

```
x - 1 + 1 = x
```

I tried to use `rewrite -> (Nat.add_comm (-1) 1).` to change the current goal to `x + 1 - 1`, but it gave me the error `Error: Cannot interpret this number as a value of type nat`. How can I solve this question?

Comment: This is probably linked with scoping issues, but your excerpt is not enough to debug… Could you provide more context? Ideally, code that can be run by others and that presents the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `x` is indeed a natural number, I believe your goal is false. Note that subtraction on the natural numbers is truncated. Thus, if `x = 0`, what we have is

```
0 - 1 + 1 = (0 - 1) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1 != 0
```

where the parenthesis I added are already there, I just made them explicit (*).

The error you get makes perfect sense. `-1` is not a natural number, and hence Coq can't interpret it as a natural number.

(*) You can do this with `Set Printing Parentheses`.

---

Edit: If you are able to prove that `1 <= x` in your context, you can use

```
Nat.sub_add: forall n m : nat, n <= m -> m - n + n = m
Nat.add_sub_swap: forall n m p : nat, p <= n -> n + m - p = n - p + m
```

I found these results by importing `Arith` and searching like so:

```
Search (_ - _ + _).
```